# Absolute DIV height 100%

Tags: css, html, height, absolute

I have been working on this for the past couple of hours, and searching the web and stackoverflow hasn't been much support. How do I make `#gradient` and `#holes` fill the entire page?

I have used the Inspect Element feature in Safari, and when I highlight the body element it does not fill the entire window.
[image]

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="gradient"></div>
    <div id="holes"></div>

    <div id="header">Header Text</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-image:url(../Images/Tile.png);
    background-color:#7D7D7D;
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

#gradient {
    background-image:url(../Images/Background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;

    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    right:0px;
}

#holes {
    background-image:url(../Images/Holes.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;

    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
    height:100%;
    right:0px;
}

#header {
    background-image:url(../Images/Header.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;

    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;

    padding-top:24px;
    height:49px; /* 73 - padding */

    color:rgb(113, 120, 128);
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:#FFF 0px 1px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to use javascript/jquery for this? if so, that's proabably a reasonable way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: There is nothing stopping me, except my dislike for it

Comment: Why not just set their heights to something obscene then? If they stick to the top of the page anyway then it shouldn't be an issue !

Comment: Which Safari version? I don't have Mac, but I can't reproduce this at any (recent) browser at my Windows XP dev machine, including Safari 4.0.4.

Comment: Safari Mac Version 4.0.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it looks to me that your element with all the content is floated. If it is then its not going to expand the body unless it is cleared.

Comment: I think he might have it, totally missed that as the css for the content box wasn't posted!

Answer (score 38):

Note that the *height* property specified in *percentage* is [calculated with the respect to the containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) ..which doesn't necessary have to be the immediate ancestor – ["The containing block for a positioned box is established by the nearest **positioned ancestor** or, if none exists, the **initial containing block**"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos). I bet this is what's going on in the questioner's case as there is no positioned ancestor (the one with `position:` set either to `relative` or `absolute`).

So the "containing block" resolves to the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#viewport) which corresponds with the dimensions of the viewport (window). Setting `position:relative` to `body` will take the `body`'s height into account and stretch the absolutely positioned content along `body` completely.

[More on containing block here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

Answer (score 17):

I was having the same issue. Fixed it by changing position: absolute to position: fixed.

Comment: Developing a mobile menu and this worked for me better than previous answers.

Comment: Dude! Been searching how to solve this for a whole day! This was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Was searching for an answer for hours! Should be accepted as best answer.

Answer (score 3):

***[update]***
**new approach**
This should do it ..

using `display:table` on your 2 elements should do it (*it works in my tests*). (but you wil have to assign width values now..

However i am not sure if you should define nested elements as table-cell etc.. which would become unmanageable..

Have a try though ..

---

*old non working version*
Have you tried on `#gradient` and `#holes` the following ?

```
#gradient {
  height:auto!important;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  ..
  ..
}
#holes{
  height:auto!important;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  ..
  ..
}
```

Comment: yes .. i posted without checking .. it will only work for the overflowing element .. (the one whose content will go beyond the bottom of the viewport..)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.class').css({'height':(($(document).height()))+'px'});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use javascript. min-height is not supported by every browser.

Javascript using prototype:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var height = $(document.body).getHeight();
document.write('<div id="yourdiv" style="height:'+height+'px;width:100%;"></div>');
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure writing the div into the page directly is the best idea: why not use $('#divName).css('height', height) instead [or the prototype equivalent]?

Comment: No need to use javascript. If you must have compatibility with IE6 (blech!) since IE < 6 treats height incorrectly as min-height, it's better to use the star html hack:

* html #gradient {
height:100%;
}

Comment: Least amount of visitors will be using windows, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up like this?

```
#holes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Will stretch the element to fill the whole page area

Answer (score 0):

I think you did it right. This is working in Chrome (WebKit too!) and in IE7/8/Quirks whenever you put width: 100% on #gradient and #holes, can't test safari on Mac right now (only have it at home) but in theory you should be seeing it properly.

That said, maybe this is a doctype thing, try different ones?

Comment: Tried XHTML 1.1, 1.0 Transitional, 4.01 Transitional

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think I'm just going to `overflow:auto` on my content so that the entire page does not need to be scrolled

Answer (score 0):

Apply the CSS styles to both #gradient & #holes & put the script after your DIV.

```
.background-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

<body>
    <div id="gradient"></div>
    <div id="holes"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
            $('#gradient,#holes').height(bodyHeight);

        })
    </script>


    <div id="header">Header Text</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, in order be able to specify positions of a container's (A) child containers (B1, B2, ...), it's position should be absolute.  Your `body` container's position isn't.

I guess you should add the `position:absolute;` property to the `html,body` selector.